# How to invert "He was never silly." to emphasize the negative adverb?

Tags: sentence-construction, inversion

What is the correct sentence if you want to make inversion for the following sentence to emphasize the negative adverb?

> He was never silly.

> 1. Never was he silly.

This is recommended as correct form in my grammar book, but I feel kind of awkward about the 'silly' which is left behind and separated from the 'never'.

> 2. Never silly was he.

I feel this is correct.

> 3. Never silly he was.

My friend thinks this is correct, because there should be no inversion in case the subject is a pronoun. But I heard that the be-verbs or do-verbs and subjects should be inverted in case the negative expressions are placed in the head of the sentence.

Please help me make correct inversion.

Comment: I don't understand why any grammar book would "recommend" inverting *He was never silly* to *Never was he silly*. That version is extremely "marked" (abnormal use of English) that would probably only ever occur in ***poetry*** (where the normal rules of syntax are often ignored). You second and third alternatives are so unnatural you'd probably never encounter either of them in *any* context. What I think you need to learn is that there's rarely any good reason for a non-native speaker to want to invert an English utterance (except where *required*, as in forming a ***question***).

Comment: Thus, the standard sequence is *He was silly*, which is inverted when asking the question *Was he silly?* That's about all you need to know.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for, but how about: "He was never not silly" - that is much more commonly used, particularly with 'not' emphasised in some way.

Comment: People would understand you in the same way as they understand the character Yoda in the Star Wars franchise who uses a non-standard word order. But it would sound very odd. I would suggest "He was never silly, never" if you want to emphasise never.

Comment: @mdewey: Good point. In which case perhaps what OP needs to learn is that the "standard" way of emphasising ***never*** (apart from the obvious ***say it loud, write it in bold and/or italics***) is *He was **never ever** silly.* Definitely ***not*** "use inversion".

Comment: Just for helping you understand why I, a non-native speaker, would like to know about this kind of 'odd' inverted sentences, I say that we do some exercises to comprehend the inverted sentences like 'Never did I dream of becoming rich when I was a kid' as these are very common in English grammar test. Of course, I simply say 'I never dreamed of becoming rich' when I make my own statement. Thanks for very helpful comments of yours.